# Postgresql 9.1 - Find difference between two databases

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have a specific architecture to set up with postgresql.

I have a system that is based on two databases N and N+1.

The database N is available for clients in read only mode, and the database N+1 is available for modification for clients.
The client can also send two commands to the system:

- An "apply" command: all the modifications made on the N+1 db are kept and the new state of the system is a readonly db with N+1 data and a N+2 db with same data available for writes.
- A "reset" command: the N+1 db is dropped and a new copy of the N database is made for writes access for the users.

My first idea was to keep two databases in an instance of postgresql and perform pg_dump and pg_restore command on apply or reset command, and rename the database for the apply(N+1 -> N). The db can possibly reach the size of 8 Go, so I am currently performing test of such dump&restore on a Centos 6.7 vm.

Then I looked to the pg_basebackup command, to set up a hot standby database that will be the readonly one. The problem is that such an architecture is based on the idea of data replication from a master to a slave, and that is something I don't want since the client can ask a reset command that will drop the N+1 db.

The thing is I don't know if a system based on daily dump/restore is viable or not, or if there is with postgresql a simple way to handle two databases with the same schema and "detect and apply" the differences between the two: with that ability, I will be able , on apply command, to copy from N+1 to N only the difference, and the contrary with a reset command.

Any idea ?